# Cakephp authenticate authorize only admin without User model

Tags: cakephp, authentication, authorization, admin, acl

I have integrated the Auth component and the Acl component (and behavior) and it all works fine with the User model etc.

Now I would like to have the admin to be completely independent from the User model and the access control lists. Why? Well, because I'm trying to build a CMS which should also work if the client doesn't want a user community in his website.

So I would like the admin to be able to log in without having a user model and once the admin is logged in he should have access to everything, regardless what Acl says...

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass an option 'userModel' while declaring AuthComponent in your AppController. Hope [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) will help you. Kindly ask if it not worked for you.